# Javascript - check if lat long coordinates are within a boundary

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

I have created an array named **coordsArray** shown beneath. I have cut off the ongoing elements within the arrays as its confidential.

[image: img of coordsArray]

I have this for loop that is supposed to go through each element within the array and look if the coordinates in index values *[ 1 ]* and *[ 2 ]* are within a bounding box for London.

```
       var cityL = "ldn";
       for (var i = 0; i < coordsArray.drugs.length; i++) {
             if(cityL == "ldn"){
                            if( 51.50408 <=  coordsArray.drugs[i][1] &&  coordsArray.drugs[i][1] <= 51.42548 && -0.326542 <=  coordsArray.drugs[i][2] &&  coordsArray.drugs[i][2] <= 0.0463) {
                            console.log("test");
                            }
                   }
             }
```

This is not working at all, I was wondering if it had something to do with the coordinates within the arrays possibly being of type string? I am unsure as to how I would go about altering this. I am sure that the if statement that checks if the values (coordsArray.drugs[i](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2XoH.png) and [2]) are within the bounding box is all correct. Thanks for any guidance, I just wish to view the coordinates that fall within London, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that your data is stored as a string and you're testing it against numbers. What you need is [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).

```
if( 51.50408 <= parseFloat(coordsArray.drugs[i][1]) ) {
...
}
```

Comment: so include var x parseInt(coordsArray.drugs[i][1]) within the for loop?

Comment: Thanks, what is the , 10) part for?

Comment: You should read the documentation I linked to. The second argument is the radix (base system) used to convert the string to a number. I'm assuming you're using base-10, since you're using latitudes and longitudes.

Comment: Thanks for the help, although I still cannot print anything to the console, there are definitely coords within the boundaries declared too